# Get value of a tag in a tab in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am novice in chrome extension development, and I would like to capture the `value` of a tag in the current tab page source. How could I achieve this? Sample code would be helpful.

Comment: What sort of tag do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 query selectors using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) or [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)

The selector API is pretty huge and powerful, you can do query the DOM very easily similar to XPath but better! http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/ It was inspired by jQuery Selectors.